# How to make a ListView to look the same as when containing elements?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I have a `ListView` binded with the `ObservableList`. Initially, when empty, `ListView` has uniform color, as shown in the picture:

[image]

After adding an element to the list, it goes filled with the cells, which have their own color:

[image]

Obviously, I wouldn't like it to behave like this, so here's the **question**: How can I make the list to look like on the second picture, even when it's empty?

Answer (score 2):

The cells are styled by the cellFactory on the ListView.  Since that only fires when there is an element in the list, you could simply add an empty value to the list when there is nothing there.

```
ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
list.add("");
ListView<String> listview = new ListView<>();
listview.setItems(list);
```

Then when something is added, remove the empty value.  Little bit of a hack, but should give you the desired visuals.

Comment: Thank you, but I know that "hack". Just thought there's something simplier ;)

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you have to account for this special case any time you work with the data: i.e. you pollute the logic in your data model with this workaround for the view. OTOH, I don't really see any real hook to do this with - the implementation in the skin of laying out the cells in the virtual flow is only invoked if the number of items is > 0, so you would have to implement a custom skin (which would turn into a bit of a project).

Comment: @James_D - I totally agree, but couldn't find a less intrusive way to handle it.  I do think that for this use case, it wouldn't be too hard to handle the edge case.